# What happens to costume pieces, powersets etc. when I drop to freemium?

Tags: city-of-heroes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Unlocked Things Stay Unlocked After Paid Time Expires?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33449/do-unlocked-things-stay-unlocked-after-paid-time-expires)

I used to play CoH Trials and for the past 2 years have played 14 trials, sometimes continuously and sometimes on and off. Here's my question: if I have already used CoH Going Rogue on an account and then buy Architect Edition and use it, will I be able to add it to my account? Do I gain anything? Plus, I was thinking, when I revert from VIP to freemium, would I lose my GR AT's and costume pieces, aura's etc.? One more thing, do I get 2 character slots per server or only 2 slots for my entire account?

Comment: Oh heres another thing...i only bought CoH - Going Rogue after freedom launched. Will i still be able to apply the retail code and get all the benefits of the GR pack? Please God Please tell me i can.

Comment: Ah thanks but what of my other problems. Like can i apply a retail code to an account that already has a retail code applied. Also to add, i only applied this code from COH GR AFTER Freedom was launched. Do i still get the same benefits as a VIP, the costume pieces,powersets and reward tokens?

Comment: @MajorZack You seem to be asking more than one thing here - I would suggest you open a new question to ask about the things you want to know that are not covered by the possible duplicate - you stand a better chance of getting a good answer that way.